# How to implement a java tester class

Tags: java, testing, console, command

I implement an email system I have a main application class which is scanning some input from the keyboard and while input is not "q" ı have to able to add any command from console. The problem is how can i implement a tester class without changing the main application class. (I need to use already prepared commands within the tester class. They wont be entered explicitly, this means that when we test the code the prepared commands entered own its own). How can do this ? Or is it possible ?

I have 2 main method and I'm not allowed to use Junit.

this is the tester class:

```
public class CalcTester {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\burak kaya\\IdeaProjects\\Cacl\\src\\calctest.txt"));
    String line ="";
    for (int i = 0; scanner.hasNext() ; i++) {
        line+=scanner.nextLine();
    }
    String[] arr =line.split(" ");
    CalcApplication.main(arr);


}
```

application class is like that:

```
public class CalcApplication {
static Stack<Integer> number = new Stack<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    String input =scanner.nextLine();

    while(!input.equals("q")) {


            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {

            } else {

            }

    }
}
```

}

I delete inside of the application because it was unnecessary. 
My question is, the application works with scanner. On the other hand, the tester class has to use predefined commands to test this application class. How can i do that ?

Comment: Please share a [mre] of your code with us.

Comment: i assume that the text file includes predefined commands, and you already passed them as parameter, so why dont you use args variable instead of  using the input variable